# Proper mySQL command for adding URLs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem when trying to add a URL to a mySQL database.

The string is a URL:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1708867059/405000_10150426314376065_707061064_8645107_703731598_n_normal.jpg
```

The error I get is:

```
Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1708867059/405000_10150426314376065_707061064_86' at line 1
```

It seems as though it won't allow me to add a URL, I presume there is something wrong with some of the characters but I don't know what?

My SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO accounts (name,consumerkey,consumersecret,pic_url) VALUES ($twitterID,$consumerkey,$consumersecret,$picture_url)"
```

Comment: You’re probably missing the quotes surrounding the string literal.

Comment: Showing your SQL would take the whole guesswork out of things.

Comment: You are undoubtedly vulnerabel to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Great thanks for the edit. You need to quote your *string* values.

Comment: Change $picture_url to '$picture_url'.. But still: use prepared queries to prevent sql injection.

Comment: use `'` or `"` <-------- these little two thingys are very important....

Comment: Using "mysqli api" or "pdo api"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot truly **solve** this kind of problem by adding a few characters (like `'` or `"`) to your bespoke sql string!

Instead, get to know the real way to write sql in php (it's like a very badly kept secret), which is to use [PDO statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  This will allow you to use placehoders like `(:twitterID, :consumerKey, :consumerSecret, :pictureUrl)` which will accept complex variables such as urls and any of the crap users send in much more gracefully.

In the long run, this will save you a lot of trouble and time.

Comment: Can you offer any help when writing prepared statements for a simple select query like this? I've been trying all morning but all the examples have loads of extra stuff in and I don't know what I need to omit.

Comment: Well, you can try using these database/pdo wrappers:
http://pastebin.com/BQAfiFmT  Obviously they'll need some modification for your particular case, but being able to go `query_item('select count(*) from users where firstname = :name', array(':name'=>$bob));` is quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote string values and any other character that SQL will complain about, in this case it's the colon; see further down below.

```
($twitterID,$consumerkey,$consumersecret,'$picture_url')
```

or

```
('".$twitterID."','".$consumerkey."','".$consumersecret."','".$picture_url."')
```

if you wish to quote all the values.

Sidenote: You can remove the quotes around the variables that are integers.

I.e.:

This based on, and without seeing how the rest of your code looks like:

```
$picture_url = "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1708867059/405000_10150426314376065_707061064_8645107_703731598_n_normal.jpg";
```

- The error states that it is near `:` - near being just that, the colon.

```
...right syntax to use near '://pbs.twimg.com
                             ^ right there
```

You can also use:

```
VALUES ($twitterID, $consumerkey, $consumersecret, '" .$dbcon->real_escape_string($picture_url) . "')";
```

`$dbcon` is an example of a DB connection variable and based on `mysqli_` syntax.

Something you haven't stated as to which MySQL API you are using.

---

- Plus, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).